# Key down events for "f" key are only delivered sporadically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, keyboard-events

Trying to use the letter "f" to trigger an action through `keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent` in my window controller, which only sporadically works.

If I log `theEvent.characters` inside the `keyDown` function I notice that I only pick up the key event somewhere between 30%-80% of the time. It seems pretty random.

Also when the I press the "f" key and the keydown doesn't pick it up, my `NSTableView` sometimes scrolls down.

Is "f" a shortcut used by `NSTableView`s or something? What is causing this?

keyDown code:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if ([theEvent.characters isEqualToString:@"f"]) {
        if (!theEvent.isARepeat) {
            [self clickFavorite];
        }
    } else if ([theEvent.characters isEqualToString:@" "]) {
        if (!theEvent.isARepeat) {
            [self clickPlayPause];
        }
    } else {
        [super keyDown:theEvent];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other programs running that might be monitoring or altering keyboard input, e.g., TextExpander?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Nope, just double checked. BTW, it also happens for the space bar.

Comment: I suppose you'd better post your `keyDown:` code just in case. The space bar is _definitely_ picked up by `NSScrollView`s for scrolling by a page, by the way.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ahh, thanks for the space bar info. Just posted the keyDown code. I've also tried setting up Key Equivelents on the menu bar in IB, same results.

Comment: You're certain the `isRepeat` check isn't causing the problem? Tried `if ([[theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers] isEqualToString:@"f"])` or `if ([theEvent keyCode] == kVK_ANSI_F)`?

Comment: @JoshCaswell So check this out, i put `NSLog(@"%i",theEvent.keyCode);` inside the keyDown. I noticed that the keyDown doesn't even receive the event sometimes, but when it does the functions are called.

Comment: @JoshCaswell just put the same code inside my scroll view and I can see that the scroll view is getting a keyDown for "f" but not my window controller. Maybe just need to have the scrollview ignore all key down events.